# Scaling entity by screen height (simulating depth on orthographic camera)

Tags: mathematics, scale

i want my entities to be at 100% scaling (for example 128x128 pixels) when they are at 40% of the screen height (for example 480 pixels at 100%), so when they are at 41%, they are at 99% scaling (126,72x126,72 pixels).

any idea of how i can achieve this? 
thanks

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. You want your entities height to be based of a calculation that involves the entities height...?

Comment: i mean position of the screen, position y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a 2D view in which case it should be feasible to project the entity's rendered size at 100% scaling, then figure out the ratio of that value to the total viewport size and go from there.